# Flex media framework

Tags: apache-flex, frameworks, media

Does anybody know of a good media framework for Flex?
I'd like to be able to create apps that can play not only those formats that the Flex framework provides support for, but other formats as well (like wav, wma, ogg and other...).

**EDIT 13.10.2008.:** It was recently pointed out to me in the answers section that I should perhaps rephrase the question, so here goes: What I'm really looking for is a way to play various media formats in a Flex/Air app. Onekidney posted a nice answer about Ogg/Vorbis. Does anybody know of a way to play other media formats? Never mind about the portability to different platforms now. Portability would be nice, but if I can't get it, I can live without it :-).
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to make your question more specific - like, is there a way to play ogg vorbis in Flash?

Then I could answer, hell yes!  It's right [here](http://drawlogic.com/2008/10/04/as3-fvorbis-flash-ogg-vorbis-player/).

Comment: Onekidney, that's exactly the kind of stuff I was looking for. And you're right, I should rephrase the question. BTW, I haven't looked into the code yet, since for some reason I have to check it out with Bazaar (if I understand correctly) but I'll definitely do it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Flex is just a set of libraries that run on the Flash Player. You can only play media formats that Flash has built in support for, so you wont find some "media framework" which adds support for more formats.